Ubuntu 24.04 Alsamixer Failing to Load libasound_module_conf_pulse.so
I need to troubleshoot my audio config but when i try to use alsamixer i get the following error:
ALSA lib conf.c:4028:(snd_config_hooks_call) Cannot open shared library libasound_module_conf_pulse.so (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_conf_pulse.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory) ALSA lib control.c:1570:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL default cannot open mixer: No such file or directory 
i found the shared library but its at /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_conf_pulse.so
how do i resolve this? is the wrong version of alsamixer installed? why is it looking for the library in the wrong place?
i tried creating a symlink /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/ to /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/ but alsamixer wouldn't follow it.
Thanks for the help!
